# Javascript Function Stopping code from executing

Tags: javascript

I have this function in my javascript which is stopping my code from being executed and returning data, If I remove it from my file the code works perfectly, can anybody see whats wrong?

```
var TimeToRenderHours = EstimatedCoreHours/(245.76);
if (TimeToRenderHours <= 1) {
   alert('less than 1 working');
} else {
alert(TimeToRenderHours);
}
```

Sorry, I would have posted the page but its huge and very messy, Estimated Core Hours comes from

```
   var EstimatedCoreHours =  GetNumeric(NoOfFrames) * GetNumeric(RenderingHours) * GetNumeric(CoresInTest);
```

the 3 variables which are multiplied are called from input files, eg

```
var NoOfFrames = document.getElementById ("NoOfFrames").value;
```

Comment: Alerts will block execution. What you have posted does not tell use anything. Post a link to a page or more code. for example where does EstimatedCoreHours come from?

Comment: What you have posted does not explain what happens. Do you get an error? can you load the page in Firefox and look in the console?

Answer (score 0):

IF I were you i would try to check wether that 3 variables are set correctly. Maybe one of them is undefined and the getnumeric method fails. 
I don't see any error in your code.